# Voltage signal and Current Signal

Tags: voltage, current, voltage-measurement, electricity, electrical

Please give an intuitive explanation of difference between how a signal or data is carried using voltage and current?

I'm wondering even though current and voltage inevitability co-exist, why do we use the term for one concept(current or voltage)? If there is a signal out there somewhere, it is both current and voltage at the same time. But we name only one of its property.

We see in some circuits like heart rate signals or some other small signals which have to be in form of voltage in order to transfer the whole signal it to an amplifier (which has high input impedance). Even if it is voltage signal, we still have current passed to the amplifier.Why it is mentioned that voltage is transferred to input of the amplifier and why not current (when voltage causes current to pass)?

Comment: please do not repost a question and then delete the old one ... improve the old question instead

Comment: it most likely has to do with the usage of an oscilloscope to view the signal ... voltage is read very easily, current no so much

Comment: @jsotola I'd say the exact opposite – a current is easily sensed through a transistor, a voltage is brittle and must be met with high input impedance, which opens up the whole can of noise and stability worms.

Comment: High speed current signals are more immune to parasitic capacitance. No change in voltage across a low impedance input means no signal lost to parasitics. That’s why current feedback op amps are so fast!

Comment: @DavidG25 Does inductance at that scale just work out to be less significant than capacitance?

Comment: Consider that it may be useful to work with voltage or current signals also depending on the specific application. It is often better to work with voltage signals since (ideally) they allow us not to absorb power from the source: if you imagine a voltage source connected to an ideal Op - Amp, the last one will take its voltage without absorbing current, so the source is not disturbed since it does not lose power. But for instance, at high frequencies, the input parasitic capacitances of amplifiers make this reasoning not more true and so it is better to work with current signals.

Comment: I would put it this way for a simple explanation. A voltage source, say, providing 5 volts means I will try to push enough current in order to try and maintain this voltage. If this voltage source is used to signal a value such as water level in a vessel where 10 volts is full and 0 volts is empty, it will be pushing the current needed to indicate that it's half-full at 5 volts. If the load is effectively equivalent to a 1k resistor, that's 5 mA, but the load might be more like a 10k and so it will only need to push 500 uA to achive a 5 volt signal. A current signal source is the same idea.

Answer (score 2):

There can be benefits to both in different situations. And in reality, as you said, we never have a pure 'voltage' or 'current' - you have both. The key is the impedance: A high output-impedance source will have it's output current change very little if the load changes, but the output voltage will change a lot - you want your load (say an amplifier) to measure the current. A low output-impedance source will have a very small change in output voltage when the load changes, but the output current will change a lot - you want your load to measure the voltage.

Take for example the inside of an integrated circuit. If we have a voltage signal, what we actually mean is 'the voltage between two points' - usually this is between the signal wire and the ground. However, the ground is not necessarily stable - other currents are also flowing through this ground and might cause voltage drops, which will lead to errors.

A current signal will not suffer from this moving ground - a current of say 1 mA is still a current of 1 mA if you have a bit of difference in ground. (this is incidentally the same reason why industrial sensors like using current mode sensors - the long wires can cause a significant voltage drop that leads to errors if you were to use voltage-mode signalling).

There is also the matter of impedance. Some sensors have a high output impedance, such as a photo-diode. Because of this, these sensors are usually used as a current-source, and not a voltage source.

On the other hand, at low speeds, a MOSFET appears like a high-impedance input voltage-to-current (the 'correct' name is transconductance) amplifier. You want to drive it with a voltage, as it will turn this voltage into a current at its output. So when driving a MOSFET, you want a voltage signal.

Things change when you go to systems with matched characteristic impedances at higher frequencies. At that point, every device has the same impedance, and you don't really think about voltage and current anymore, and instead consider power.

Comment: I do not see why you would want to measure a current, when it changes very little.
Wouldn't it be better to measure the voltage instead?
Intuitively I would choose to measure the quantity that changes a lot, to be sure that I can detect that change.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it has to do with what the author thinks is the best way to sense the signal that's on that pair of wires.  If they say "voltage signal" then they (probably) feel that it should be applied to a high-impedance amplifier that responds to voltage; if they say "current signal" then they feel that it should be applied to a low-impedance amplifier that responds to current.

An example of a current signal is a 4-20mA current signaling loop.  A device that uses this expects to be fed a wide range and possibly varying voltage, and it will impose a current proportional to the quantity it's measuring on the power supply.

An example of a voltage signal would be the output of a typical op-amp.  The op-amp imposes a voltage which remains largely unchanged regardless of variations on the current, at least up to the point where the amplifier can no longer coerce the output to be correct.

Comment: Don't you mean 4-20mA?

Comment: @KevinWhite Thank you.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

We use the different terms because in the case of a voltage signal, the observed quantity is voltage, and in the case of current signals, current.

That's really all there is to it.

Comment: Really that’s all, what about CML?

Comment: That's a signalling standard. If I had a guess, the receivers of that observe a voltage signal and use external 50Ω termination. To be honest, this is a bit like asking whether a TV cable transports a current or voltage signal; the answer would be "yes", and also that Maxwell links these two, but the receiver observes either the current, or the voltage signal aspect.

Comment: I think in terms of implementation. CML uses emitter inputs to maximize BW at the expense of no current gain in the 1st stage and complementary current sources for drivers.  Unlike CMOS and TTL however uses voltage gain for receiving and saturated switches for driving, whereas video analog uses linear mode 75 Ohms source and load impedance.

Comment: well, doesn't that answer the question about which quantity is relevant for the input stage?

Answer (score 0):

Data transfer especially with controlled impedances is often done with either voltage or current sources with source and load impedances matching the cable transmission line.  Voltage source amplifiers are  true for single-ended or  differential drivers like RS-485.

In Current Controlled Logic ( ECL,PECL,CML)  gain in speed by using Emitter Couple speed advantages and also uses  differential line currents to reduce EMI and skew.

So both Voltage mode  and Current mode drivers are used depending on the link speed (**or rise time in ps,ns or us** )and distance.  The overlapping bit rates commonly used may be in the 100MHz to 1GHz range but are not hard limits but for >>1GHz , CML is preferred and is standard up to 10Gbps with higher levels possible.

1Gbps Ethernet links use differential voltage drivers with controlled impedance lines and the current into the matched load is used by voltage amplifying receivers. But it also uses a bandwidth compression form of modulation and compensation to make the cable less sensitive for signal integrity/ quality. They also  with BALUNs and transformers to magnetically improve the Common Mode noise rejection needed from line noise and ground noise differences.

Answer (score 0):

If a signal is 5V and 1uA (or maybe even 1nA), would you rather be inspecting the large 5V? Or the miniscule 1uA or 1nA? You probably want to look at the voltage since it is larger and easier to read, so we call it a voltage signal since that's the component you are treating as carrying the information.

But if your signal is 10mA being pushed down wire by the transmitter applying 2.5V, which would you rather inspect for data? They both seem to be magnitudes that are reasonably easy to inspect. But wait...that 10mA is a pretty high current that would have caused a voltage drop along the wires so if you inspect the voltage it won't be accurate to what is on the other end of the wire. The 10mA current, on the other hand, remains unchanged down the line and all the extra power was spent to push it down the wire so it would be a waste if you didn't take advantage of the current somehow (you could easily push 2.5V down the wire into a high impedance input so the current is much lower and therefore consumes much less power with much less voltage drop for a more accurate voltage). Why wouldn't you inspect the current for the data? So we call it a current signal.

Comment: Thank you so much for reaching out.What causes a voltage drop across the wire when you have 10mA current.

Comment: Wires have resistance. More current  means more voltage drop so you dont want to send more than is necessary if all you want is to transmit a voltage which is why you want high impedance inputs for voltage.

Comment: Could you also please explain how (high current ,low voltage) and (low current,high voltage) effects power consumption in circuits?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly what it is you want to know there. It's a really broad and vague question.

Comment: As you said, there will be voltage drop along the wires when we pass 10mA current. According to Ohm's law, current directly proportional to voltage.Because of voltage drop here, current should also reduce right? How can we measure 10mA current down the line?

Comment: You're forgetting that for a current signal, you apply whatever voltage is required to get the desired current to flow down the line (either that or you have to know the total line resistance to begin with which is unreliable and subject to variation). Since the current going in one end of the line must be the same current going out the other end, that means the transmitter can just monitor its own output current and adjust its output voltage as necessary so the current is the correct level. Essentially, your system compensates for the wire resistance.

Comment: Okay. If some current (energy) is lost in form of heat due to resistance, does the system provide more voltage greater than 2.5V in this case to provide 10 mA at the end ?

Comment: You can't do the same transmitter-side monitoring with a voltage signal to compensate for voltage sag without running another wire from the receiver all the way back to the transmitter. But with a voltage signal you design the receiver to have high input impedance so minimal current flows down the line so you have minimal voltage drop.

Comment: @rdeep Yes, that is correct. For a current signal transmitter, if the wire is longer (more resistance) the transmitter increases its output voltage until the output current is what it is supposed to be. If the wire is shorter, it adjusts it's output voltage to be less since not as much is required to push the same amount of current. Of course, there is a limit to this since a transmitter doesn't have an infinite voltage supply to run off of.

Comment: If current increases as we increase the voltage even with more resistance, how is it possible to have no current passing (or negligible amount of current ) through op-amp input with high resistance. I always wonder how can no current pass into an op-amp when we put a lot of voltage on its inputs. Please let me know.

Comment: Do not mistake ideal components for real components. Real op-amps have something called bias and offset input currents. Real MOSFET gates have leakage currents. Real diodes have a voltage drop that changes depending on the current running through it.

Comment: The input bias currents in op-amp are very less compared with the input voltage (having high input impedance at the input terminals). As you said, if there is more input impedance (resistance), more voltage will be dropped across the input terminals which should also increase the current right? But, why do we get less current into the op-amp to bias it? Why is it not good to have more input bias current ?

Comment: You're not making when you say currents are less than voltages. I'll phrase this another way. If you're choosing to work with a voltage signal, you choose an input impedance which is very high, a cable resistance that is very low. Everything is in series so this forms a divider where very little voltage is dropped at the output and along the cable and almost all the voltage is dropped across the input. This is good because we want an accurate voltage arriving at the input since that is what we are looking at for our data.

Comment: Maybe you're confusing an impedance that a signal travels through to get to the destination versus the impedance at the destination?

Comment: I understood that to get an accurate voltage at the input we will will high high impedance. But what happens to the input voltage signal that we apply? Does it get converted to the current (proportional to the the voltage signal) to bias the op-amp?

Comment: Take a look at how a transistor works.